# How did "trans-" compound with "vestire" to mean "disguise"?

Tags: etymology

Where does the meaning of "disguise" in *travestire* hail from? How does the prefix *trans*- contribute, partly or wholly, to this meaning? I'm baffled because *trans-* and *vestire* in Latin didn't mean "disguise", which appears to have first arisen in Italian.

#### travesty [17]

> *Travesty* and *transvestite* [20] are
> first cousins. Both are compounded of the Latin
> elements *trāns-* ‘across’ and *vestīre* ‘clothe’
> (source of English vest, vestment, etc), but they
> are separate formations. *Travesty* comes
> ultimately from Italian *travestire* ‘change
> clothes so as to disguise’, formed from the
> Italian descendants of the Latin elements. This
> was borrowed into French as *travestir* ‘ridicule’,
> and its past participle *travesti* gave English
> *travesty*. *Transvestite* is a new formation, coined
> in German in the first decade of the 20th century
> (although there are a couple of isolated instances
> of a verb *transvest* ‘cross-dress’ from the 1650s).

*Word Origins* (2005 2e) by John Ayto. p 515 Right column.

[travesty | Search Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=travesty)

> from Italian *travestire* "to disguise," from Latin *trans* "across, beyond; over" (see trans-) + *vestire* "to clothe" (from PIE **wes-* (2) "to clothe," extended form of root **eu-* "to dress")

Comment: I think prefix *trāns-* implies a change, in the same way that in *transformāre* there is a change in form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original meaning arose in late Latin and from there passed into Italian. "Transvestire" just meant "change clothes" (in the sense used by actors and performers). So, yes, in Latin *transvestire* almost meant "disguise" already.

This is a comment to the second book of Dante's *Comedia*, in which comment [Ghino di Tacco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghino_di_Tacco)'s murder is detailed: "Then Ghino, disguised and with fake clothes [possibly a reference to sumptuary laws?], entered the Roman Curia and publicly murdered that Aretine judge".

[image]